# 3DM-GX3-25 throws std::runtime_error() "Time is Out of Dual 32-bit range" on Ros Fuerte/Ubuntu Precise

Tags: ros, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to get the 3DM-GX3-25 Inertial sensor up and running on Ros Fuerte/Ubuntu Precise using the [Microstrain 3dM-GX2 IMU node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/) in the Microstrain 3dM-gX2 package.

When I run the node, I get the following error:

---

> jdavis@MyUbuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu$
> rosrun microstrain_3dmgx2_imu imu_node

> [ INFO] [1345843227.742138299]:
> Connected to IMU [      3DM-GX3-25]
> model [       6223-4220] s/n [
> 6223.06644] options [       5g 300d/s] [ INFO] [1345843227.742460665]:

> Calibrating IMU gyros.
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'   what():  Time is out of dual 32-bit range
> Aborted
> (core dumped)

---

I looked it up on answers.ros.org and saw that a similar error was thrown in rosbag file playing ([this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/9280/slam_gmapping-mappingfromloggeddata-out-of-dual-32-bit-range/)) and ([this one)](http://answers.ros.org/question/10651/slam-gmapping-tutorial-troubleshooting/).

The IMU timestamps are measured in Uint64_ts and converted to Doubles for calculations, before converting them back to Uint64_t. Is this what I should be looking at?

Any ideas on how I can get around this would be great!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42258/3dm-gx3-25-throws-std::runtime_error()-%22time-is-out-of-dual-32-bit-range%22-on-ros-fuerte/ubuntu-precise/) by [jdavis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3079/jdavis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdavis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3079/jdavis/) on 2012-08-27**:
I got it to work by replacing data.header.stamp = ros::Time::now().FromNSec(time) to data.header.stamp = ros::Time::now() in the function getData() inside the imu_node.cc source file for the node. Conversion to ros::time threw the error?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thanks, this solution worked for me too. I wish they have a look at it and integrate the solution or a better solution to the driver.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-04-15**:
@jdavis I suggest you file a ticket here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/issues so that the maintainers know there is an issue. Before doing so, try to see if Groovy includes a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this the same issue?

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5601

If so, just apply that patch, or do apply like it was fixed for Groovy:

https://github.com/ros-drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/commit/efcf5ef011a97f8bda415616075ed85a5bfcb962

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0